# Alternative to file-locking to ensure only one instance of application can be launched

Tags: java, io, distribution

I'm using `file.deleteOnExit()` and `file.exists()` to ensure that only one instance of my application can be running at any given point in time. However I'm starting to see major flaws in the method:

1) You can duplicate all files surrounding the locked file and run the executable.

2) If the JVM process is ended forcefully, the locking file is not deleted.

What (other than socket-locking perhaps) would be a good alternative?

**EDIT:**
Using a socket to lock to only one process works well and is very clean but I've heard of potential conflicts with other applications and firewalls. For example, if the port chosen is for some reason in use by another process, my application will think that another instance is already running - which is why I'd like an alternative solution to that.

Comment: Do you want to lock the file for the multi threaded environment ?

Comment: The file will be empty, simply used to check if another instance is already running. IMO a naive approach, though I can't think of another concise solution without the potential for conflict (such as with socket-binding).

Comment: If the app. has a GUI, use the [`SingleInstanceService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/SingleInstanceService.html).

Comment: One of the more common solutions I've seen to this problem is opening a server socket on a local port.  If you can connect to it, then another application is running.  The problem with this approach is two folder.  1. You may hit fire wall/restriction issues; 2. You face race conditions

Answer (score 1):

You can use FileChannel#lock() method for multi-JVM locking:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(".lock", "rw");
FileChannel fileChannel = raf.getChannel();
fileChannel.lock();
```

Don't forget to release all resources carefully when you are done.

Comment: I've tried this but the problem was that you can still delete the file outside of the JVM, in which case multiple instances can be run.

Comment: I seem to recall (and it may have changed) the `FileChannel#lock` is OS specific and may not be available or all OS's

Comment: I've used this approach on Linux and Windows, still can't guarantee it will work everywhere.